# How can i catch the exception and continue without exiting the program

Tags: go

I am passing a list of urls from a text file. command as below

```
cat urls.txt | ./mygofile
```

it stops if it sees a broken url. How can I make it continue without exiting the program? I want it to show a simple error and continue to the next URL without exiting

```
http://beap.adss.yahoo.com/
http://id.answers.yahoo.com/search
https://brokenurl
http://id.answers.yahoo.com/KnowledgeSearchService
http://id.answers.yahoo.com/question/nextQuestion
```

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "crypto/tls"
)

func main() {
    passedUrl := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    var pUrl string
    for passedUrl.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(passedUrl.Text())
        if strings.Contains(passedUrl.Text(), "://"){
            pUrl = passedUrl.Text()
        } else {
            pUrl = "https://" + passedUrl.Text()
        }

        body := "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
        customTransport := &(*http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport))
        customTransport.TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
        client := &http.Client{Transport: customTransport}
        client.CheckRedirect = func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
            return http.ErrUseLastResponse
        }

        req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", pUrl, bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(body)))
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8")
        resp, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        defer resp.Body.Close()
        var responseHeaders string
        for headerName, value := range resp.Header {
            responseHeaders += headerName + ": " + value[0] + "\n"
        }

        if strings.Contains(responseHeaders, "text/xml") {
            fmt.Printf("Match Head: ")
            fmt.Printf(pUrl)
            fmt.Println("")
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the error am getting

[image: error]

Comment: Go doesn't have the same try/catch concept that for example Java has. What you encounter is a panic, there are ways to recover from panics, but I would rather write the program in a way that you don't access values that are null. https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover

Comment: Do not paste images of text. They're very hard to read for the best of us, and impossible to read for the visually impaired. They also can't be indexed or searched. Just copy and paste your text into the question instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now your script don't interrupt the loop, all you need it stop execution and skip to the next `pUrl`. Something like this should work:

```
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8")
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
   log.Println(err)
   continue // stop here and process next item
}
```

More about [`for loops`](https://gobyexample.com/for)

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the error, but ignoring it:

```
        resp, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
```

At this point, `resp` is nil, because the call failed. If there is error, you should not continue processing the result. Handle the error here in `if` statement, or return the error to the caller so that it can handle it.

Comment: Note that the code does not include a solution. It is your code. You have to handle the error somehow.

Comment: it says line 45 is the issue.. which is "defer resp.Body.Close()" would be great if you could help me a bit more